# How change color of the underline of Edittext on 4.0+?

Tags: java, android, colors, android-edittext

I have on my app Theme.Holo but I want to change the color of the underline border of edittext.

I don't want a full border around the edittext. I just want to change the color of the edittext layout on version 4.0+ .

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can change android:background to your desired drawable to replace your edit text's default background.

Comment: I combinate your answer with Peregreen's. I downloaded a 9patch file from http://android-holo-colors.com/ . And set android:background on this drawable.

Answer (score 5):

You could use 9patch. This resource is wonderful example: [android holo](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

Comment: Do you have a tutorial or something, where it's explained how to implement it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

or Android-holo-colors can generate 9patch files to you.

Answer (score 4):

```
int color = Color.parse("#HEX")
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 3):

For those that want a more complete answer. The default color is actually a 9- patch background. So you will need to replace it.

Go to http://android-holo-colors.com/. Here you will see a category called "color".

Click on the colored square beside it and you will see a color swatch come up. Change the color to that desired.

Scroll down and find another category called EditText. Click the yes button beside it.

Finally scroll down to the end of the page and download the generated zip.

Decompress the zip on your computer. You will find a couple of drawable folders according to the different pixel densities. Copy them to the appropriate folders in your project.

There will also be a folder simply called "drawable". In it will be an xml file. If you have a folder called "drawable", different from "drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc", copy the xml file to the "drawable" folder, else create one in your "res" folder

Lastly, copy the name of the xml file. Go to the EditText you would like to change and set the xml file as your background. If your xml file was titled edit_text_holo_light, the xml code you would put in your EditText would be:

```
android:background="@drawable/edit_text_holo_light
```

Save the project and run.

Comment: That would cause the whole EditText (not just the underline) to change color.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Not necessarily. The background, underline etc are all set from that file. In this case, the rest of EditText is left the same. Only the underline is changed.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky You must have changed something in your code somewhere. The image doesn't look like the Android 4.x design pattern. I am presently using the solution above in one of my apps and it works fine. I only changed the underline. Also ensure you picked the right compatibility and theme at the link above.

Answer (score 2):

use `android:backgroundTint=""` in your EditText xml layout

Comment: `backgroundTint` is api 21 and up.

Comment: Yes but you can always use AppCompat Views like AppCompatEditText at Support libraries dude

Comment: @SoheilSetayeshi I think the AppCompat version of widgets are for extending them into custom implementations. If you use "SwitchCompat" for example, Android will still use the regular "Switch" Widget by default.

Comment: @hitch.united By using AppCompat widgets like AppCompatEditText you can color your EditText tint using mEditText.setSupportBackgroundTintList() instead of mEditText.setBackgroundTintList() which needs API 21 ;)