# Changing bottom line colour of edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am trying to change the bottom line colour of EditText but it is showing default blue line colour.I failed to understand where am I going wrong?

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/usericonlayout"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Search for all GIFs"
        android:textColorHint="#A0A0A0"
        android:shadowColor="@color/border_gray"
        android:theme="@style/EditTextStyle"/>
```

styles.xml

```
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/border_gray</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
    </style>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/border_gray</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
    </style
 <style name="EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/border_gray</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/border_gray</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/border_gray</item>
    </style>
```

I also tried -

```
edittext.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.border_gray), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

but didn't worked

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-to-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571816/how-change-color-of-the-underline-of-edittext-on-4-0

Answer (score 5):

I think you are trying to implement material design in your app.
First of all there should be only two values folder in your res folder.
1. values (For version < 21)
2. values-v21

styles.xml for version < 21

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        ....
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
         <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/border_gray</item>
         <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/border_gray</item>
         <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/border_gray</item>
</style>
```

And for v21

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
    .....
     // Your style here
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Api lvl >= 21, then you have to put the "android:" namespace in front of every attribute you listed.

If you are using AppCompat, you have to change your Theme's parent to:

```
@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light
```

Answer (score -1):

here it is..

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableBottom="@color/yourColor"/>
```